# Showing a non-ASPX Web Page in SP?

Tags: web

I want to show a non-ASPX web page on my SharePoint page.

Can I somehow add a basic web page that shows up (maybe as an IFrame) on my SharePoint page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Page Viewer web part. This works exactly like you described. It provides a webpage in an IFrame form. Check out more about this here. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Mike. So permissions work as if it were a separate browser window then?

Comment: That is correct.